# Moving/renaming files with %2f in their name into a directory structure

Tags: files

I have a bunch of files that were exported (from my [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org) wiki) that are named like `ParentPage%2FSubPage` but they actually should be like `ParentPage/SubPage`. Anyone have a quick and dirty way to rename and organize them, so that `ParentPage` will be a directory, and then `SubPage` will be a file inside that?

---

Slightly modified from @Christopher Karel's answer, which is what I used:

```
for FILE in $(ls | grep "%2F")
do
  CONVERTED=$(echo $FILE | sed -e 's/%2F/\//g')
  DIRNAME=$(dirname $CONVERTED)
  if [ -f $DIRNAME ]; then  mv $DIRNAME $DIRNAME.page; fi
  mkdir -p $DIRNAME
  if [ -f $DIRNAME.page ]; then  mv $DIRNAME.page $DIRNAME/$(basename $DIRNAME); fi
  mv $FILE $CONVERTED
done
```

and the test data I used (in an empty dir), before running the above:

```
touch Test; touch Test%2FA%2F1; touch Test%2FA%2F2; touch Test%2FB
```

Comment: Judging by the directory slash, i'd assume *nix

Comment: Linux (Ubuntu 9.10, specifically), though could also be for Windows 7 (I have a feeling this is way easier on Linux though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here's a bash method to do this.  Not foolproof, but quick and dirty.

```
for FILE in $(ls | grep "%2F")
do
CONVERTED=$(echo $FILE | sed -e 's/%2F/\//')
mkdir -p $(dirname $CONVERTED)
mv $FILE $CONVERTED
done
```

Comment: Thanks, that basically did the trick. I had to add a quick check because I didn't think of the situation where there is already a file with the target directory name (that now gets moved to the new directory), and I modified it slightly to handle multiple levels of directories. I'll post my version